# How To Work With Multiple .py Files In One Project Solution Python VS

Tags: python

For the last 6 months I have been learning python and practicing with the logic of python. However, as I continue to become more advanced, I find that I just have more and more to learn. One question that I have encountered is how to work with multiple files in one project. An example of what I am trying to do is: If i have a solution that is running predictive analysis on stock data being scraped from the web, and I want to compare these results with SP500 data, I am currently using two different projects and comparing the data by hand. As you can imagine this is extremely inefficient and leads to more errors than benefits. When learning C# and VB.NET in visual studios, there was a way to create multiple forms for a GUI, and reference those forms from other forms. While I know this is not the same as what I am trying to ask, I am wondering if there is a way to work with multiple .py files in one solution, each having their own logic, and reference these different files from other files.

Comment: There is an `import` system that you can use to logically separate code into different files and import into a single, master, script.

Comment: [Let me google that for you](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-modules-in-python-3)

Answer (score 2):

If you had a file like start.py and then things.py held functions, objects, or classes...

start.py

```
import things
from things import config

things.printline(config)
```

things.py

```
config = 'This is a variable assignment'

def printline(line):
    print(line)
    return line
```

It's really that easy.  You can also store several files into a directory and just import the directory the same way, you just need to have an empty `__init__.py` file in it.  Your import would be

```
import folder.nameofmodule
```

Comment: Would there possibly be a way to say run the script holding the logic, and then have a separate script for my graphs and run those asynch?

Comment: Sure, that is what Gevent and AsyncIO are for.

Answer (score 1):

I focus only on your core problem:

> If I have a solution that is running predictive analysis on stock data
>   being scraped from the web, and I want to compare these results with
>   SP500 data, I am currently using two different projects and comparing
>   the data by hand.

My advice is not to combine different projects *for the sake of comparing output*. Don't let any interface or environment *decide* how you structure your code.

Code structure is dependent on *what you are actually doing*. If you need to compare outputs of 2 different classes from different projects, write a script to calculate and compare results from your 2 classes:

**comparer.py**:

```
import Class1
import Class2

Class1Instance = Class1.ClassOne()
Class2Instance = Class2.ClassTwo()

res1 = Class1Instance.get_results()
res2 = Class2Instance.get_results()

def compare_results(x, y):
    return func(x, y)

compare_results(res1, res2)
```

If there are specific tests your scripts should satisfy, consider using [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) from the standard library.

Comment: if i understand what you are saying correctly, you are suggesting writing 2 separate scripts to for the logic, and then writing a 3rd script to compare the 2 scripts?

Comment: My understanding is you *already have* 2 different projects: "I am currently using two different projects." If you need to write a `unittest` and perform other testing functions, comparing 2 other projects, then yes, that's absolutely a good reason for a 3rd project/script.